# How to generate and display a sequence (loan exercise)

Tags: c#, sequence

I would like to create a sequence, where:

```
a0 = 1100000
a1 = 1100000 * 1.012 - 25000
a2 = (1100000 * 1.012 - 25000) * 1.012 - 25000
a3 = (1100000 * 1.012 - 25000) * 1.012 - 25000) * 1.012 - 25000  
...
```

Problem is, it only calculates/displays `a1` (1088200), one hundred times. (I want to store it all in an array called ms)

Below is the code I've come up with:

```
double interest = 1.012;

int[] ms = new int[100];

for (int i = 0; i < ms.Length; i++)
{
    int a0 = 1100000;
    ms[i] = Convert.ToInt32(a0 * interest - 25000);
    a0 = ms[i];

    Console.WriteLine(ms[i]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: move declaration of a0 outside loop. as it is now it's redeclared to be 1100000 each time loop runs.

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring a new `a0` variable in each iteration of the loop, and always initializing it with the value 1100000. If you want to use the value from the previous iteration within the loop, you need to declare it *outside* the loop:

```
int a0 = 1100000;
for (int i = 0; i < ms.Length; i++)
{
    ms[i] = Convert.ToInt32(a0 * interest - 25000);
    a0 = ms[i];
    Console.WriteLine(ms[i]);
}
```

Note that yo'll be losing precision on each iteration - you might be best to keep `a0` as a `double` (or `decimal`) and only cast when storing:

```
decimal interest = 1.012m;
decimal current = 1100000;
for (int i = 0; i < ms.Length; i++)
{
    current = current * interest - 25000;
    ms[i] = (int) current;
    Console.WriteLine(ms[i]);
}
```

Comment: you sir are my savior, i am much obliged!